# Force SSL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, heroku

I know there are lots of similar (read: identical) questions, but I've tried everything - doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^developers/(.*)$ api/web/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

 # Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
  RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Everything I get is only a redirect loop.

I'm using Heroku.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the last rule? `#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]`

Comment: @PanamaJack, yes I did. I use CloudFlare's DNS and I've purged the cache. 
@starkeen no, I cannot remove the last rule because I use Yii2 framework for PHP and there is no other way to access my frontend app - only by `https://app.example.com/frontend/web/user/create/` (e.g.) and I want to access by `https://app.example.com/user/create/` (e.g.)